# Slow query while using DISTINCT in MYSQL with various other conditions (10 million records)

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-rds, social-networking

I am working on a social Network where, as usual there is a feed for users where they are able to see the activities of users a user is following and not the users who are blocked by the users.

This is the query that is being used currently  from the Activities table

```
SELECT DISTINCT `activities`.`post_id` 
FROM `activities` 
WHERE (activities.user_id IN ([followed_user_ids]) AND 
activities.language_id IN ([language_ids]) AND 
activities.id <= ?) AND 
(`activities`.`post_user_id` NOT IN ([blocked_and_deactivated_user_ids])) 
ORDER BY `activities`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10
```

This is the query which is causing issues. Sometimes the Mysql CPU usage goes to 100% which causes issues to the users. I have also used index on the columns being used in the activity table.

There are 10 million records in the Activities table.

What changes can i possibly do to optimise this?

Comment: Did you try you to tweak your mysql settings? Can you post your my.cnf? Did you try mysqltuner? Did you try to look into
    log_slow_queries and
    log-queries-not-using-indexes?

Comment: Do you really need `DISTINCT` here?

Comment: You could make 'temporary' tables storing each subset

Comment: @slowjack2k I didn't try tweaking mysql settings, It generally works fine but under higher traffic the query slows down a lot i,e. around 20 secs, and freezes the database. 
Is it because i am using IN in this query, and since the followed_user_ids can be in 1000's is this the reason of concern?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I need to find out distinct activities by post so that a user doesn't see same post multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for a production DB on RDS, I would suggest creating a [Read Replica](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/), and divert all those heavy SELECT queries to the replica. Here's [the link to the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html#USER_ReadRepl.Create).
Doing this you will mitigate the freezing issue for your users, as the heavy queries are not going to be executed on the same instance as the usual workload.

Secondly, consider creating indexes for the tables involved on those heavy queries. To choose wisely which indexes to create, use the [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) statement and check the main bottlenecks, i.e. where the query is taking more steps to fetch the correct data.

If you really cant get rid of those IN statements (I think that at least some of them you should be able, like followed users ids and languages, maybe you can replace the IN's by simple joins using the user id) create indexes for the involved columns.

Let us know how it goes.